# Android 1.6 losing Packets

Tags: android, localhost, serversocket

just encountered the following on Android 1.6 (Sony Xperia X10): When requesting data with XMLHttpRequest in a WebView on the same device (eg. 127.0.0.1:8080) while serving packets via `ServerSocket.accept()`, the XMLHttpRequest sometimes get stuck. The debugger tells me that the server actually is deep into `ServerSocket.accept()`, eg. he has served or not received the last request. The WebViewCoreThread is stuck at

```
Object.wait() line: 288 
Request.waitUntilComplete() line: 381   
RequestHandle.waitUntilComplete() line: 262 
Network.requestURL(String, Map, byte[], LoadListener, boolean) line: 195    
FrameLoader.handleHTTPLoad() line: 204  
FrameLoader.executeLoad() line: 131 
...
```

supposedly waiting for it's `http0` ... `http3` threads, that all wait at

```
Object.wait(long, int) line: not available [native method]  
RequestQueue(Object).wait() line: 288   
ConnectionThread.run() line: 93
```

First I thought the request packet just got lost. But that doesn't explain why all `http..` threads are at the same waiting position, as one should wait for response, while the others for new jobs from WebView then. Any ideas?

Comment: The mentioned waiting of the `http..` threads is actually a "waiting for jobs" position. So the workers wait for work while the `WebViewCoreThread` wait for their completion. Seems to be a bug.

Comment: This is indeed a bug in Android it seems, I reported that. As the request to answer delay of the server raises, the problem occurs less and then vanishes. So maybe this will never show up on real network requests and can only be reproduced with a localhost server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in Android it seems. It can be circumvented by adding a delay to the server before the response is sent.